# Javascript actions not working in mageneto

Tags: javascript, magento

I'm working on this theme and I wanted to create this simple nav that would fadeIn on click and fadeOut on click.

```
<div id="mobile-nav">
    <a class="exit"></a>
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="center">
        <li class="skincare">Skincare</li>
        <li class="makeup">Makeup</li>
        <li class="kits">Kits</li>
        <li class="help">Help</li>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
           $(function() {
                    $('.exit').click(function(){
                        $('#mobile-nav').fadeOut();
                    });
                }
</script>
```

However it doesn't seem to work when I try it out. Other types of script like swiper.js works, but this simple script doesn't work. Is there anything wrong with what I'm doing? I've been checking for errors and jQuery is loading as well.

Live preview here - http://magazine.eldecosmetics.com/

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
$(function() {
                        $$('.exit').invoke('observe', 'click', function() {
                            $('#mobile-nav').toggleClass('fadedOut');
                        });
                    });
```

Your code is

```
$(function() {
                    $$('.exit').invoke('observe', 'click', function() {
                        $('#mobile-nav').toggleClassName('fadedOut');
                    });
                }
```

Comment: Thanks! Changed it, but nothing happening with the exit button yet.

Comment: Also try changing it to toggleClass instead of toggleClassName

Comment: Tried That. Still doesn't work. Simply can't understand Prototype.js...

Comment: I see why. jQuery conflicted with prototype.js. I'm glad you solved it. You should do the same with $('#notice').slideDown(1000);

Answer (score 0):

In Magento try to avoid jquery conflicts you must use **jQuery** instead of **$** symbol.

For example i have mentioned the correct coding

```
jQuery(function(){

            $$('.exit').invoke('observe', 'click', function() {
                jQuery('#mobile-nav').toggleClass('fadedOut');
            });

});
```

Hope it will helps to you guys.